# How to increase the size of the mdtextfield inside a BoxLayout --kivy

Tags: python, kivy, textinput

I want to create a **Textfield** with a particular **size_hint** and once the text inside the field reaches a particular `minimum height` than the Textfield **size_hint** will be set to *None* and `y_scroll` will get active..Seems perfect when using `FloatLayout`. But when I am using a Boxlayout the size of the `MDTextField` seems not to change . if I change it's size_hint to suppose `0.7` then the textfield `Having mode set to rectangle` will become a line and if keep it to None and changes its height via `height` property the size doesn't increase.. How can I fix the problem .. Any solution except for changing the layout because only BoxLayout is the thing which I want/Use

my code::

```
str = '''
    
MDCard:
    pos_hint : {'x':0.056 , 'top':0.836}
    size_hint : 0.88,0.82
    
    ScrollView:
        do_scroll_x : False
        BoxLayout:
            height : self.minimum_height
            orientation : 'vertical'
            size_hint : 1,None
            spacing : 15
            padding : 55
            
            MDTextField:
                id : input_field_1
                mode : 'rectangle'
                size_hint : None,None
                height : 500            # setting height doesn't seems to work either
                #y_scroll : True if self.minimum_height > 400 else False
                multiline : True

            MDTextField:
                id : input_field_2
                mode : 'rectangle'
                size_hint : None,0.7 # see the result 
                #y_scroll : True
                multiline : True

'''
class My_4app(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(str)
My_4app().run()
```

Any help is quite appreciated

Answer (score 1):

It has been 3+ years so the OP probably already figured this out. But if somebody else came here for the same issue, you just need to set max_height in MDTextField to that minimum, which will force it to scroll once the size hits that limit.

In the code above, just replace:

```
height : 500
```

by

```
max_height : 400
```

or whatever value you want as a threshold.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for bringing some closure to this question! Do you happen to have a reference to relevant documentation?

Comment: Unfortunately no. The two main KivyMD online documentation pages for 1.x and 2.0 don't really go into that detail.